# Whether the gtalk have any limitations on number of contacts or number of messages per minute/hour/day?

Tags: xmpp, google-talk

We plan to use gtalk for creating chat bot. My question is Whether the gtalk have any limitations on number of contacts or number of messages per minute/hour/day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to run gtalkbots.com which was using google apps infra including jabber service. One of the utility bot called games@gtalkbots.com used to send/rcv about 100-150 chat messages per second at one point without any blockage from google app servers.

Also i think if ever you get such a warning, it will be appropriately told to you with error stanza from google talk servers. Error message should read something like "policy violation" etc... Hope this info helps.....